# Find the number of ways to place $n$ people into $n$ chairs (circular table) so that a particular pair has exactly $k$ people between them.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Find the number of ways to place $n$ people into $n$ chairs (circular table) so that a particular pair has exactly $k$ people between them.

If they were seated in a row at a table, then the answer would be $2(n-k-1)(n-2)!$ since the pair can be placed in $n-k-1$ ways and they can interchange their seats in $2! = 2$ ways and the others can be seated in $(n-2)!$ ways. I can't figure out what changes with a circular table.

Comment: If it is a circular table, how do you define "between them"? Clockwise/anti-clock?

Comment: clockwise @ShubhamJohri

Comment: The wording of the question says "a particular **pair** has exactly has exactly *k* people between them", so clockwise/anticlockwise is  irrelevant. It would enter the picture only if it measured the gap from a particular **person**

Comment: @trueblueanil I agree that clockwise/anticlockwise is irrelevant, as long as one of the two is specified.  Alternatively, if the orientation is unspecified, then as N.F.Taussig commented, following my answer, unless $k,n$ are such that either orientation has the two people directly across from each other, then an unspecified orientation implies that you have an extra factor of $(2)$.

Comment: @trueblueanil On the other hand, now that I think about it, in a purely formal sense, you are absolutely right.  However, when the OP specified a clockwise direction, I inferred that the OP intended that this specification would not be irrelevant.  This means that the OP intended that it would be clockwise with respect to one of the two people.

Comment: @user2661923: Yea, it just depends on whether you go with the text of the question or with OP's opinion on it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Shubham, you should precise what definition you put on "between them". If an orientation is given (for example if you look at the number of chairs between them, counted in the anti clock sense), then I think that the answer is $2(k+1)(n-2)!$ plus the answer for a row table. Indeed, there are $k+1$ more options for chosing the two places, then you order the pair, then you order the others.

Try to bend your row table and join the extremities to see where the difference comes from.

Comment: I disagree: see my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 our approaches give the same result, if we consider that rotating everyone's position affect the seating, and that there are two possibilities for the order of $P_1$ and $P_2$. Your answer gives $2n(n-2)!$, and mine gives $2(k+1)(n-2)!+2(n-k-1)(n-2)!=2n(n-2)!$.

Comment: @good point, other than the issue that the OP specified a clockwise direction between the two people (in a comment following the answer), which would nullify the factor of $(2)$.    Besides that, my bad for blindly assuming that your answer had to be wrong, because it did not *appear* to be independent of $k$.

Comment: @user2661923 No worry, actually I think the problem deserved to be seen as independent of $k$, so you did right to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments following the question, and the comments following this answer, for a *debate* about whether the answer(s) below need to have a factor of $(2)$ applied [assuming that $n,k$ are not such that P-1 and P-2 are *across* from each other].

---

Denote the pair as P-1, P-2.  Without loss of generality, you can construe the position of P-1 as the *head of the table*.  Then, **regardless** of the value of $k$, the exact seating position of P-2 is **fixed**.

This implies that the overall computation is $(n-2)!.$

---

Note, that I am presuming that rotating everyone's position at the table does not alter the seating.  Alternatively, if you reject this presumption, then you have to multiply the above computation by a factor of $(n)$, since there are $n$ different people who could be at the *head of the table*.

Think of it like a Poker game at a round table, where once each person's seat is fixed, the dealer position rotates.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the reply, it's nice to know that I'm not the crazy one.  I agree with your analysis, except that the OP responded with a comment, following the question.  The OP specifically designated a *clockwise* orientation, for the seats between the two people.  This seems unambiguous to me: this means that once P-1 is seated, P-2's seat is fixed.

Comment: Thinking about the problem again, P-2 can be $k + 1$ seats to the right or the left of P-1.  You seem to be assuming that P-2 must be on a particular side of P-1.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, see the comments, following the answer.  From a purely math point-of-view, as true blue anil indicated, the OP's comment that he intended a *clock-wise* orientation is **meaningless**.  As I commented, I don't think that the OP's intent is that orientation (clockwise or counter-clockwise) would be irrelevant.  Therefore, my inference is that the OP *wants the orientation to matter*.  This is the basis for my omitting the factor of $(2)$.  However, as true blue anil's comment indicated, the OP hasn't given any formal justification for the factor of $(2)$ being omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $k + 1 < n$ to avoid ambiguity and so that one person does not sit in the other's lap.

Suppose Amanda and Brian are the two people in question.  By convention, in a circular arrangement, only the relative order of the people matters.  Seat Amanda.  We will use her as our reference point.  If there are exactly $k$ people between them, then Brian can be seated in two ways unless $n = 2(k + 1)$, either $k + 1$ seats to Amanda's left or $k + 1$ seats to her right.  However, if $n = 2(k + 1)$, Brian is both $k + 1$ seats to her left and to her right, so he can be seated in only one way.  In either case, the remaining $n - 2$ people may be seated in the remaining $n - 2$ seats in $(n - 2)!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from Amanda.  Hence, the number of ways to place $n$ people in $n$ chairs at a circular table if a particular pair has exactly $k$ people between them is
$$
\begin{cases}
2(n - 2)! & \text{if $n \neq 2(k + 1)$}\\
(n - 2)! & \text{if $n = 2(k + 1)$}
\end{cases}
$$